# Instantiate the fabcar and return the Failed to get policy manager for channel

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I have started the chaincode-docker-devmode.
and the changed the sacc to fabcar
Compiled the fabcar.go to fabcar success.

```
docker exec -it chaincode bash
CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer:7051 CORE_CHAINCODE_ID_NAME=fabcar:0 ./fabcar

docker exec -it cli bash
peer chaincode install -p chaincodedev/chaincode/fabcar -n fabcar -v 0
```

At this time all the process is success
then i execute the

```
peer chaincode instantiate -n fabcar -v 0 -c '{"Args":["init"]}'  -C mycar
```

the console told me :

```
2017-10-18 10:59:50.945 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 001 Returning existing local MSP
2017-10-18 10:59:50.945 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 002 Obtaining default signing identity
2017-10-18 10:59:50.945 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 003 Sign: plaintext: 0AA4080A5C08011A0C08A6E89CCF0510...6E666967426C6F636B0A056D79636172
2017-10-18 10:59:50.945 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 004 Sign: digest: 38FA755F94FA90784C50D77E8638EA42679C0F8216AA3DBE10A7D8D2F2215D80
Error: Error getting (mycar) orderer endpoint: Error endorsing GetConfigBlock: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = chaincode error (status: 500, message: "GetConfigBlock" request failed authorization check for channel [mycar]: [Failed to get policy manager for channel [mycar]])
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Chaincode instantiate in fact endorsement transaction which has to be eventually submitted to the ordering service, hence what you missed in the instantiate command is the ordering service endpoint, e.g.:

You did:

```
peer chaincode instantiate -n fabcar -v 0 -c '{"Args":["init"]}'  -C mycar
```

While needed:

```
peer chaincode instantiate -o orderer.example.com:7050 -n fabcar -v 0 -c '{"Args":["init"]}'  -C mycar
```